# What is the use of creating type properties in Swift?

Tags: swift

What is the use of type method in swift can anyone give the realtime usage example? because I see it has not been used in any instance of the class

```
class SomeClass {
    static var name=0
    SomeClass.someTypeMethod()
}
```

Comment: With out initialising class you can call them where every you want

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the analogy of a car factory. We'll create a `Car` class. You can think of the `Car` class as the factory that builds `Cars`. You use an initializer to build new cars.

The class itself does work that affects all cars: sets prices, orders supplies, schedules payments, etc. An individual car provides transportation.

Say cars have FM radios, and they come with a default set of station presets. You might have a type method that changes the set of default stations that are programmed into a new car. Once you've changed the default stations, new cars built by the factory would have different default stations.